# Looking for an R script that can do the following: if value x of column A contains certain string then write y in a new column B

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a new variable in R based on another variable. Basically what I want to do is: if value x in column A contains a specific string of characters, then (in a new column) write y.

So for example, in my dataset, I have a variable called "condition" which has the following unique values:

```
[1] "05_CL_dom" "16_CF_sub" "02_CL_sub" "01_CL_dom" "19_CF_dom" "14_CL_sub" "17_CL_dom" "10_CL_sub" "09_CL_dom" "15_CF_dom"
[11] "18_CL_sub" "06_CL_sub" "20_CF_sub" "12_CF_sub" "04_CF_sub" "08_CF_sub" "24_CF_sub" "11_CF_dom" "21_CL_dom" "22_CL_sub"
[21] "23_CF_dom" "07_CF_dom" "03_CF_dom" "13_CL_dom" "06_CL_dom" "07_CF_sub" "16_CF_dom" "03_CF_sub" "12_CF_dom" "11_CF_sub"
[31] "17_CL_sub" "14_CL_dom" "21_CL_sub" "20_CF_dom" "22_CL_dom" "19_CF_sub" "01_CL_sub" "08_CF_dom" "15_CF_sub" "13_CL_sub"
[41] "18_CL_dom" "09_CL_sub" "05_CL_sub" "23_CF_sub" "10_CL_dom" "24_CF_dom" "04_CF_dom" "02_CL_dom" "18_CF_sub" "05_CF_dom"
[51] "02_CF_sub" "03_CL_dom" "21_CF_dom" "01_CF_dom" "12_CL_sub" "19_CL_dom" "20_CL_sub" "23_CL_dom" "16_CL_sub" "22_CF_sub"
[61] "04_CL_sub" "11_CL_dom" "10_CF_sub" "06_CF_sub" "14_CF_sub" "07_CL_dom" "15_CL_dom" "08_CL_sub" "24_CL_sub" "13_CF_dom"
[71] "09_CF_dom" "17_CF_dom" "19_CL_sub" "13_CF_sub" "10_CF_dom" "16_CL_dom" "05_CF_sub" "09_CF_sub" "06_CF_dom" "03_CL_sub"
[81] "08_CL_dom" "14_CF_dom" "17_CF_sub" "21_CF_sub" "01_CF_sub" "24_CL_dom" "23_CL_sub" "22_CF_dom" "07_CL_sub" "18_CF_dom"
[91] "20_CL_dom" "04_CL_dom" "11_CL_sub" "02_CF_dom" "12_CL_dom" "15_CL_sub"
```

Based on these values I want to create a new variable called "conditionNEW": 

 - if a value of condition contains CL_sub -> CLsub

 - if a value of condition contains CL_dom -> CLdom

 - if a value of condition contains CF_sub -> CFsub

 - if a value of condition contains CF_dom -> CFdom

Right now, what I did is:

```
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "01_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "02_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "03_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "04_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "05_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "06_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "07_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "08_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "09_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "10_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "11_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "12_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "13_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "14_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "15_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "16_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "17_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "18_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "19_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "20_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "21_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "22_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "23_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "24_CF_dom"] <- "CFdom"

rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "01_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "02_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "03_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "04_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "05_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "06_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "07_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "08_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "09_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "10_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "11_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "12_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "13_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "14_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "15_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "16_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "17_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "18_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "19_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "20_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "21_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "22_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "23_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "24_CF_sub"] <- "CFsub"

rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "01_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "02_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "03_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "04_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "05_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "06_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "07_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "08_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "09_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "10_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "11_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "12_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "13_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "14_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "15_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "16_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "17_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "18_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "19_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "20_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "21_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "22_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "23_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "24_CL_dom"] <- "CLdom"

rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "01_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "02_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "03_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "04_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "05_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "06_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "07_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "08_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "09_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "10_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "11_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "12_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "13_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "14_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "15_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "16_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "17_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "18_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "19_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "20_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "21_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "22_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "23_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
rawdata$conditionNEW[rawdata$condition == "24_CL_sub"] <- "CLsub"
```

It works, but it's a lot of code for something that feels like something that should be rather simple. Is there anyone who knows how to do this with less code?

Comment: if you want to match a pattern you can just so something like `rawdata$conditionNEW[grepl("CF_dom", rawdata$condition)] <- "CFdom"`. You can replace all those lines of code with just 4, one for each pattern.

Comment: Thanks! I found out the second after I posted it. Apparently why it didn't work when I tried grepl for the first time, was because my condition variable was a factor.

Comment: You shouldn't edit your question to include an "answer". If you answered your own question, you should put that as an answer below. I rolled back your edit. You can also still delete if you prefer.

Comment: Ah okay, good to know, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can use ifelse statements

```
rawdata$conditionnew <- ifelse(  
    grepl( "CL_sub" , rawdata$condition ) , "CLsub", 
    ifelse(   
        grepl( "CL_dom" , rawdata$condition ) , "CLdom",
        ifelse( 
            grepl( "CF_sub" , rawdata$condition ) , "CF_sub",
            ifelse( 
                grepl( "CF_dom" , rawdata$condition ) , "CF_dom", NA))))
```

You can also use regular expressions here:

```
rawdata$conditionNEW  <- gsub( "[0-9]|_" , "", rawdata$condition  )
```

Comment: Thanks! I found out the second after I posted it. Apparently why it didn't work when I tried grepl for the first time, was because my condition variable was a factor.

Comment: try my second approach, it is even easier

Comment: I think the 4th `ifelse` statement is unnecessary as all the data are described by the above conditions so that there is no need for NA. So this should suffice: `rawdata$conditionnew <- ifelse(grepl("CL_sub" , rawdata$condition), "CLsub", 
                               ifelse(grepl("CL_dom" , rawdata$condition ) , "CLdom",
                                      ifelse(grepl( "CF_sub" , rawdata$condition ) , "CF_sub", "CF_dom")))`

Comment: That's true.  It just seems safer to me.  But your point is taken

Comment: @Iris. Your conclusion about the reason for failure with `grepl` is not correct. It works fine with factor input. The code for `grepl` will first do an `as.character` operation on factors.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann I think MatthewR is correct in saying that his method is safer. You method would assign "CF_dom to any remaining items regardless of their value. That might not be the intent or desire of Iris (or future readers of this post.)